# post method in MVC Web API in knockout js

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

i need samples and examples for post,delete,put method on MVC web API with Knockout js. i got an error while running Post method in MVC web API.

Here my code for Post Method:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'api/product/PostProduct/',
   cache: false,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   data: ko.toJSON(Product),
   success: function (data) {
       alert('added');
       self.Products.push(data);
       self.BrandName("");
       self.price("");
       self.GenericName("");
    }
 }).fail(
       function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
           alert('error');
    });
```

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: it will not post into server. it returns data as ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST-URL is not like REST. Are you Sure having the 'POSTProduct'-Suffix serverside?